# All ones in binary representation

Tags: java, binary

I was going through some examples in Cracking the coding interview book. In the bit manipulation chapter, author has used the following to create a all ones binary representation

```
int allOnes = ~0;
```

I was just wondering, why can't we simply do

```
int allOnes = -1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can. Let's try it and see

```
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(-1));
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(~0));
System.out.println(~0);
```

Output is (as you might have guessed)

```
11111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111
-1
```

Because `~0` **is** `-1`. [JLS-15.15.5. Bitwise Complement Operator `~`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.5) says (in part),

> At run time, the value of the unary bitwise complement expression is the bitwise complement of the promoted value of the operand. In all cases, ~x equals (-x)-1.